# How to root OnePlus 9 Pro without flashing a boot image

Tags: rooting, oneplus

I remember how I rooted Samsung Galaxy S3: I got a SuperSU ZIP file, placed it in a sd card root folder then after powering the device off entered the stock built-in recovery and added this ZIP file using it. That was all.

Now for OnePlus 9 Pro I see that the manufacturer supports bootloader unlocking, but then the support ends. I have to get somewhere the boot image and flash it using Magisk. Is there some no-flash version that just adds `su` and keeps the stock ROM, whatever is currently installed?

Comment: The common way is to download a firmware update for your phone model and extract the boot image from the update.

Comment: I would first ask in a community that is dedicated to that phone model. Rooting on theoretical and practical level are some time to totally different topics. For rooting best site is xda-dev: https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/oneplus-9-pro.12153/

Comment: one can't flash from Magisk, this step is done from fastboot